# TypeError: req.flash is not a function (NodeJs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

Working with Registration in a Site. For the register Form,Validation is done using mongoose models and trying to Use **Flash** to display the error message in the Form.

But struct at this error

> TypeError: res.flash is not a function
>       at /home/work/first-node-app/firstnode/routes/index.js:35:11

My Code snippets Follows below

> App.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var session = require('express-session');
var flash        = require('connect-flash');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var commonKeys = require('./config/config');


var app = express();

//connect mongoDb 
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db', { useNewUrlParser: true });

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// required for passport session
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secrettexthere',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  // using store session on MongoDB using express-session + connect  
}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.use('/', indexRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

> Index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/user-model');
var Local = require('../config/passport-local');

router.get('/register', function(req, res){
  res.render('public/register',{title:'Register'});
});


router.post('/register', function(req,res,next){
  User.create({name:req.body.name, password:req.body.password, email : req.body.email}, function(err, user){
    if (err) {      
      console.log('Error Inserting New Data');

      if (err.name == 'ValidationError') {
          for (field in err.errors) {
            res.flash(field, err.errors[field].message); 
          }
          res.render('public/register');
      }
    }
    if(user) {
      res.send('user registered');
    }    
  })    
});

module.exports = router;
```

Can anyone point out the error in this code snippets, as am new to Nodejs and Trying to work out the Form validation. **The validation Works fine and the console displays the error but i can't pass that using flash. Can anyone Help me?** *And its much appreciated if you confirm my approach to code Nodejs is in correct way*.

Comment: have you installed the required packages

Comment: yes i  do installed `connect-flash` `flash`  `req-flash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use req.flash() in place of res.flash. Refer [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash) for more clarification.